# number of users who makes a purchase in google analytics exploration is different from the actual

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I create a purchase event using GA4 measurement protocol from my own backend, because I can't log the event directly from my mobile app. and I can get the correct number of users who makes a purchase (15) in the last 30 days if open the 'Event' tab in my Google Analytics console like this

[image]

and then I try to create funnel exploration. I just make only one step to ensure the purchaser count is correct, here is the setting of my step for funnel exploration

[image]

and here is the result for the same date range. I only have 5 users who makes a purchase. I expect it will be 15 users

[image]

I create purchase using GA4 measurement protocol using the json payload like this

```
{"app_instance_id":"d87a8f85123e6b961f916f33f4043e7c","user_id":"1","timestamp_micros":"1667707452423000","non_personalized_ads":false,"user_properties":{"customer_type":{"value":"regular"}},"events":[{"name":"purchase","params":{"items":[{"item_name":"import/china/sea","item_category":"lcl","price":200000,"currency":"IDR","item_category2":"checkout"},{"item_name":"import/china/air","item_category":"air","price":400000,"currency":"IDR","item_category2":"checkout"}],"coupon":"JAKARTA2025","currency":"IDR","transaction_id":"INC1621","value":600000}}]}
```

[image]

what went wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

Users in your Funnel are broken down by platform (Android and iOS), but your event via measurement protocol doesn't contain platform.

More than data may not be in sync between explorations and reporting, data freshness may be different.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12233314#data-processing